# AngularJS communicating between server using websocket to reload automatically

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I want to do something like if in my database field happens any delete/get/post/put operation, these kind of change should be reflect in client side too without refreshing.

I mean, when any change occurs, the server should send an alert to client to refresh or reload the page automatically.

I achieved this kind of job with `$interval` but i know this is not a good practice. so i dont i want to achieve with this.

I want to achieve this with `websocket` or some other good way but not getting how to do it.

here you go for my current snippet that solved with `$interval` :

```
app.controller('crudCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

  $scope.getAllContact = function() {
    var data = $http.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/contact/")
    .then(function(response) {
      $scope.contacts = response.data;
      $scope.getAllContact();
      $interval($scope.getAllContact, 10000);
    }, function(response) {
      $scope.getAllContact();
      $interval($scope.getAllContact, 10000);
    });
  };
  $scope.getAllContact();
```

Above snippet works very nice to refresh the page in every millisecond but this is not good practice, coz, it hits to database with too `GET` request.

So i want to implement this with `websocket` or whatever other good way

But i am not getting how to do it and where.

Can anyone fix me this issue?

Optional: in my database, there are four field, `userid, name, email, phone` so i want to do refresh the page automatically if any of this field is edited/deleted/added or whatever change happens

Comment: SignalR is your friend - it will automatically work out the most efficient communication method be it WebSockets, server send events, forever frame, etc. There are a multitude of articles discussing how to use SignalR with AngularJS. [Here is one such article](https://www.sitepoint.com/build-real-time-signalr-dashboard-angularjs/) that should get you started. Come back with any specific questions you may have after you've given it a try.

Comment: Yes, i see those article but i couldnt do it yet